# Reduce if-else statements with Java8 Streams while filtering multiple conditions

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8, java-stream

I got a review comment from my peers that i need to reduce the use of multiple If-else blocks in my code and instead use imperative programming techniques to achieve the same functionality

**Background**
I have a List of Events and i need to return an event object based on few conditions.For an SOP Event and SOP Acknowledge Event the size of the list could be 2 or 3, for a Non-Sop Acknowledge event the size is 2 but event type is different, finally there is a single event where the size is 1.

```
//All Required Predicates

//SOP Special Event
if(eventList.size() >1 && results.getAcknowledgeUid().isEmpty()){
       event = eventList.stream().filter(isOriginalEvent.and(isSOPEvent).and(isSOPSpecialEvent))
                                 .findFirst().orElse(null);
} 
else if (eventList.size() >1 && !results.getAcknowledgeUid().isEmpty()) {
       // SOP Acnknowledge Event
       if("SOP".equalsIgnoreCase(eventList.get(0).getEventType())) {
           event = eventList.stream().filter(isAcknowledgeEvent)
                                     .findFirst().orElse(null);
       }
       // Non SOP Acnknowledge Event
       List<event> eventAcnknowledgeList = repository.findEventByUid(results.getAcnknowledgeUid);
       event = eventAcnknowledgeList.stream().filter(isAcnknowledgeEvent)
                                       .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
// Single Event
else if (eventList.size() >0) {
       event = eventList.stream().filter(isOriginalEvent).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

I moved all my conditions within in the if else blocks to predicates and it's looking compact right now. But i'm still unable to reduce the if-else chain. I considered using ternary operator to merge the second and third blocks, but the code is looking clumsy if i did that.
i'm unable to do the following as well.

```
Predicate<List<Event>> isMoreThanTwoEvents = event -> eventList.size() > 1;

 event = eventList.stream().filter(isAcknowledgeEvent.and(isSOPEvent).and(isMoreThanTwoEvents))
                                 .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

which gives me an error in the IDE

> Required type Predicate <? super Event>
> Provided Predicate <List>

1. How do i reduce the If-Else Chaining?
2. How do i filter data in Streams within a Collection that are outside the scope of that collection?
3. Is there a better or elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least that block is wrong:

```
   // SOP Acnknowledge Event
   if("SOP".equalsIgnoreCase(eventList.get(0).getEventType())) {
       event = eventList.stream().filter(isAcknowledgeEvent)
                                 .findFirst().orElse(null);
   }
   // Non SOP Acnknowledge Event
   List<event> eventAcnknowledgeList = repository.findEventByUid(results.getAcnknowledgeUid);
   event = eventAcnknowledgeList.stream().filter(isAcnknowledgeEvent)
                                   .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

there is a (probably) missing else, isn't it?

```
   // SOP Acnknowledge Event
   if ("SOP".equalsIgnoreCase(eventList.get(0).getEventType())) {
       event = eventList.stream().filter(isAcknowledgeEvent)
                                 .findFirst().orElse(null);
   } else {
       // Non SOP Acnknowledge Event
       List<event> eventAcnknowledgeList = repository.findEventByUid(results.getAcnknowledgeUid);
       event = eventAcnknowledgeList.stream().filter(isAcnknowledgeEvent)
                                   .findFirst().orElse(null);
   }
```

The ifs are;

```
if (n>1 && cond)
else if (n>1 && !cond)
else if (n>0)
```

at least testing `cond` twice is redundant. You may write it:

```
if (n>1)
    if (cond)
    else
else if (n>0)
```

and if `n` is always 1, 2 or 3 then the last test may be removed:

```
if (n>1)
    if (cond)
    else
else
```

which gives:

```
if (eventList.size()>1) {
    if (results.getAcknowledgeUid().isEmpty()) {
        event = eventList.stream().filter(isOriginalEvent.and(isSOPEvent).and(isSOPSpecialEvent))
                                 .findFirst().orElse(null);
    } else { 
       // SOP Acnknowledge Event
       if("SOP".equalsIgnoreCase(eventList.get(0).getEventType())) {
           event = eventList.stream().filter(isAcknowledgeEvent)
                                     .findFirst().orElse(null);
       } else {
       // Non SOP Acnknowledge Event
           List<event> eventAcnknowledgeList = repository.findEventByUid(results.getAcnknowledgeUid);
           event = eventAcnknowledgeList.stream().filter(isAcnknowledgeEvent)
                                       .findFirst().orElse(null);
       }
else {
       event = eventList.stream().filter(isOriginalEvent).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

You may also factorize the calls to findFirst.orElse and filters:

```
Stream<SOMETYPE> s = null;
Predicate<SOMETYPE> f = null
if (eventList.size()>1) {
    if (results.getAcknowledgeUid().isEmpty()) {
        s = eventList.stream();
        f = isOriginalEvent.and(isSOPEvent).and(isSOPSpecialEvent);
    } else { 
       if("SOP".equalsIgnoreCase(eventList.get(0).getEventType())) {
           s = eventList.stream()
       } else {
           s = repository.findEventByUid(results.getAcnknowledgeUid).stream()
       }
       f = filter(isAcnknowledgeEvent);
else {
       s =  eventList.stream();
       f = isOriginalEvent;
}
event = s.filter(f).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @JeanBaptiste Even as i am nesting through the if else blocks, i hope my review will get passed as this is very concise and clear.This will help me design my code better in future as well.

Answer (score 2):

Streams and predicates are not a silver bullet, and there's nothing wrong with plain `if`s.

A small refactoring, mainly removing redundant conditions, yields:

```
if (eventList.size() > 1) { //SOP Special Event
    if (results.getAcknowledgeUid().isEmpty()) {
        event = eventList.stream().filter(isOriginalEvent.and(isSOPEvent).and(isSOPSpecialEvent))
                .findFirst().orElse(null);
    } else {
        if ("SOP".equalsIgnoreCase(eventList.get(0).getEventType())) { // SOP Acnknowledge Event
            event = eventList.stream().filter(isAcknowledgeEvent)
                    .findFirst().orElse(null);
        } else { // Non SOP Acnknowledge Event
            event = eventAcnknowledgeList = repository.findEventByUid(results.getAcnknowledgeUid)
                    .stream().filter(isAcnknowledgeEvent)
                    .findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
} else { // Single Event
    event = eventList.stream().filter(isOriginalEvent).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

which has good readability.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use early returns.

E.g.

```
if(foo) {
 return "foo";
}

if(bar) {
 return "bar";
}

etc...
```